# socket TCP server program problems

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp

The following code is my TCP server program:

```
    #include
    #include
    #pragma comment (lib,"ws2_32.lib")
    #define PORT 8888
    #define ADDR "127.0.0.1"
```

`int main()
{
    WSADATA wsock;
    SOCKET listensocket,connectsocket;
    SOCKADDR_IN seraddr,cliaddr;
    int cliaddrsize=sizeof(cliaddr);
    int nret=0;
    char buf[100];

    printf("init socket ...\n");
    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsock)!=0)
    {
        printf("WSAStartup() failed %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
        return 0;
    }
    printf("init successfully\n");
    printf("create TCP socket...\n");

    if((listensocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP))==INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("socket create failed %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    printf("socket create successfully\n");

    seraddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    seraddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(ADDR);
    seraddr.sin_port=htons(PORT);
    if(bind(listensocket,(SOCKADDR *)&seraddr,sizeof(seraddr))==SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("bind failed %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(listensocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    printf("bind successfully\n");

    if(listen(listensocket,5)==SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("listen failed %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(listensocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    printf("wait for a connection on port %d\n",PORT);

    if(connectsocket=accept(listensocket,(SOCKADDR*)&cliaddr,&cliaddrsize)==INVALID_SOCKET)  //accept
    {
        printf("accept failed %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(listensocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    printf("get connection from %s : %d successfully\n",inet_ntoa(cliaddr.sin_addr),ntohs(cliaddr.sin_port));//NB 啊
    closesocket(listensocket);

    printf("wait to receive data...\n");
    memset(buf,0,sizeof(buf));
    while(1)
    {
        if(nret=recv(connectsocket,buf,sizeof(buf),0)==SOCKET_ERROR)      //recv
        {
            printf("recv failed %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(connectsocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 0;
        }
        printf(buf);
        printf("\n");
        if(strncmp(buf,"exit",sizeof("exit"))==0)
        {
            printf("exit the loop\n");
            break;
        }
        if(nret=send(connectsocket,buf,sizeof(buf),0)==SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("send failed %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
        }
    }
    closesocket(connectsocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}`

And I use my network debugging assistent software to run as a TCP client. As follows:

I started my TCP server program, it went as follows:

(...cannot upload images...)

But when I click on my TCP client, the TCP server went wrong :
the dos box shows that : recv failed 10038

My question is why it went wrong ? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
if(connectsocket=accept(listensocket,(SOCKADDR*)&cliaddr,&cliaddrsize)
       ==INVALID_SOCKET)
```

will result in `connectsocket` having a value of `0`, which does not refer to a valid socket descriptor which the error code `10038` means:

> An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.

because of [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence):

```
// Result of this will be 0 (false) when result of accept()
// is not `INVALID_SOCKET`
accept(listensocket,(SOCKADDR*)&cliaddr,&cliaddrsize) == INVALID_SOCKET

// Which is then assigned to connectsocket
connectsocket = 0

// And the failing if branch is not entered
if (connectsocket)
```

You need parenthesis around the assignment:

```
if((connectsocket=accept(listensocket,(SOCKADDR*)&cliaddr,&cliaddrsize))
    ==INVALID_SOCKET)
```

which you have already done for the earlier call to `socket()`.

Comment: you said it!! it worked!! But another question: still the code above, I set the TCP server IP address "127.0.0.1", and the TCP client(my network assistent software) cannot connect to it with "1035 error".I just set the IP address my public IP "222.195.80.96". After that, it worked well... But why? I cannot use localhost or something else?

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in line :

```
if(connectsocket=accept(listensocket,(SOCKADDR*)&cliaddr,&cliaddrsize)==INVALID_SOCKET)  //accept
```

It should be:

```
if((connectsocket=accept(listensocket,(SOCKADDR*)&cliaddr,&cliaddrsize))==INVALID_SOCKET)  //accept
```

Notice the **parenthesis**. In your original code you are assigning the result of the comparison to a **connectsocket** variable (which will be always zero as a result).